# GTK+ multiple carets on one edit text box

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk3

I'd like to create more than one caret on a text control box in GTK+. I've been taking a look at GtkSourceView but it doesn't seem that extensible. How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Chances are you're going to have to write your own widget (and I have very little idea how exactly you'd go about doing that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extra caret by using a [`GtkTextMark`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextMark.html) on which you have called `gtk_text_mark_set_visible (mark, TRUE);`. (Don't forget that as a subclass of `GtkTextView`, `GtkSourceView` has a lot more API than would seem at first glance.)